# Websphere 8.5.3, SLF4j Log4j, Multiple EARs, multiple log files not generating

Tags: log4j, slf4j, ear, websphere-8

I have two EARs deployed to Websphere 8.5.3 with different log4j configurations. But the server is only generating one log file. If I deploy the EARs individually, the server is generating the log file , but when both the EARs are deployed only one log file is being generated by the server. I have the slf4j-log4j jars on the class path and one lo4j.properties in each EAR's WAR module.
Can anyone please help me understand whats going on with the Websphere JVM or if I am doing something wrong

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO
log4j.logger.com.code.first=INFO,appOne
log4j.appender.appOne=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.appOne.Name=ApplicationLogAppender
log4j.appender.appOne.File=/logPath/AppOneLog.log
log4j.appender.appOne.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.appOne.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.appOne.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.appOne.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %-5p %t - %m%n
log4j.appender.appOne.Threshold=DEBUG
log4j.appender.appOne.Append=false


log4j.rootLogger=INFO
log4j.logger.com.code.second=INFO,appTwo
log4j.appender.appTwo=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.appTwo.Name=ApplicationLogAppender
log4j.appender.appTwo.File=/logPath/AppTwolog.log
log4j.appender.appTwo.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.appTwo.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.appTwo.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.appTwo.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %-5p %t - %m%n
log4j.appender.appTwo.Threshold=DEBUG
log4j.appender.appTwo.Append=false
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

> I have the slf4j-log4j jars on the class path

Does that mean the same log4j JAR is shared between the applications?  There may be a problem that the log4j classes are loaded just once and shared between the applications.  Can you try putting the log4j JAR in each web module WEB-INF/lib folder?  That will give each of the web modules its own load of the log4j classes and may resolve the problem.  (Also, since log4j classes are also used by the server, make sure to have the web modules load classes from themselves first.)

Thomas Bitonti, IBM WebSphere Application Server Development

Comment: Thank you for responding. 
Yes. I removed the maven dependencies.
Every Web module has the jars in the WeB-INF/lib folder. Also I have explicitly set the class loading preferences as parent last for the WAR modules

Comment: Does the problem still occur with the changes, or was it resolved?

Comment: If the problem still occurs, can you display the class loader which was used to load the logger classes: Logger logger = getSomeLogger(); System.out.println("Logger [ " + logger + " ] ClassLoader [ " + logger.getClass().getClassLoader() + " ]");

Comment: posted the issue above as it was too big and I dont have the privilage to edit my post.

Comment: It appears that the log4j configuration can't be found.  (Per the "faq.html#noconfig" in the log4j error output.)  Can you double check the configuration file locations?

Comment: But the log file was being created and updated too.
I found out that I didnot put the slf4j log4j jars in the lib folder for the first app, and hence it was reading from the sharedlib.Also the "Manage Module" option worked for me to set PARENT_LAST class loading instead of "Class loading and update detection" option on the console. I will again work on adding the jars in the first app's lib folder and test again. I could not remove these jars from sharedlib because other jars have dependency on them and the RestServlet wasnt initializing. 
Thanks tbitonti for your help.